# Zend 2 subquery columns

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework2, subquery, expression

I want to create a SQL(MySQL) query in Zend Framework 2 like:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.age, 
       (SELECT MAX(score) 
        FROM scores AS s 
        WHERE s.user_id = a.id) AS max_score,
       (SELECT SUM(time) 
        FROM games_played_time AS gpt 
        WHERE gpt.user_id = a.id) AS time_played
FROM users AS a
ORDER BY last_visited DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Mind that this is an artificial example of existing query.

I tried creating sub-queries and then creating main select query where when I use:

```
$select->columns(
             array(
                   'id', 
                   'name', 
                   'age', 
                   'max_score' => new Expression('?', array($sub1),
                   'time_played' => new Expression('?', array($sub2)
                  )
```

I also tried using:

```
$subquery = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("({$sub->getSqlString()})")
```

And even lambda functions like suggested here: http://circlical.com/blog/2014/1/27/zend-framework-2-subqueries-subselect-and-table-gateway

Still no luck because all the time I keep getting errors like:

> No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

And when I succeed in making the query work, it ends up that column contains the text of sub-queries. It starts to look that it is not possible to make multiple expressions in columns method. Any ideas?

**SOLVED:**
I rewrote query by query as @Tim Klever proposed. Everythin worked except one query. It turns out there is some kind of issue when using limit in subquery and in main query. In my case one of the subqueries returns multiple rows, so I ussed limit(1) to force return of a single value. But using that turned out to produce error:

> No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

I changed the query to use MAX instead of limit and now it works. Later will try to debug why this is happening.. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me to produce the query you listed

```
$maxScoreSelect = new Select();
$maxScoreSelect->from(array('s' => 'scores'));
$maxScoreSelect->columns(array(new Expression('MAX(score)')));
$maxScoreSelect->where->addPredicates('s.user_id = a.id');

$sumTimeSelect = new Select();
$sumTimeSelect->from(array('gpt' => 'games_played_time'));
$sumTimeSelect->columns(array(new Expression('SUM(time)')));
$sumTimeSelect->where->addPredicates('gpt.user_id = a.id');

$select = new Select();
$select->from(array('a' => 'users'));
$select->columns(array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'age',
    'max_score' => new Expression('?', array($maxScoreSelect)),
    'time_played' => new Expression('?', array($sumTimeSelect))
));
$select->order('last_visited DESC');
$select->limit(100);
$select->offset(0);
```